# Is it possible to add javascript extensions in google 's V8 JS engine?

Tags: javascript, webkit, v8

With http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtwebkit-bridge.html we can expose Qt 's QObject as glabal JS objects in browser, this helps in exposing native functionality, or to expose new set of JS helper APIs, Currently QtWebkit has implemented QtWebkit bridge on top of JavaScriptCore.

Is there any way to expose native C++/C objects/structures in Google 's V8 JS engine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  See the examples under http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/extensions/?r=8431 that extend `v8::Extension` which I believe are manipulated via [`api.h`](http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/api.h#144).

You can also create objects to expose to V8 and intercept property accesses on them via [property interception](http://code.google.com/apis/v8/embed.html#interceptors).

Comment: Any hope of this still existing in ppapi/pnacl/nacl? My goals require that I can create native objects that the javascript environment can directly call. Message passing won't work for my task.

Answer (score 0):

You may prefer writing an [NPAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Plugins) plugin than a V8 extension since V8 engine is sandboxed by default within Chromium. That means your extension cannot access external resources out of sandbox neither. Some libraries, such as [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org), may help you write an NPAPI plugin easier.

Comment: @SunnyShah that's no help whatsoever.